# Quarter formula that adds up incrementally from a specific date and also takes Year into consideration?

Tags: date, excel-formula

In Microsoft Excel:

I am trying to create a normal cell formula for calculating number of Quarters from a specific date (12/1/2024).

But I want months between
12/1/2024 - 12/31/2024 to be Qtr 1
1/1/2025 - 3/31/2025 to be Qtr 2
4/1/2025 - 6/30/2025 to be Qtr 3
7/1/2025 - 9/30/2025 to be Qtr 4
10/1/2025 - 12/31/2025 Qtr 5
1/1/2026 - 3/31/2026 Qtr 6
and so on for 40 years.

Reflect the respective quarter numbers for month with respect to each quarter.

[Expecting something like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgdTo.png)

I am using

````
=ROUNDUP(YEARFRAC($B13,H4)*4,0)
```, 


Please help!


[The result I am getting][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAbRH.png
````

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Microsoft Excel

Answer (score 0):

Using a start date of 11/30/24 in A2, building up step by step gives us:
`=INT((((YEAR(D1)-YEAR($A$2))*12+MONTH(D1)-MONTH($A$2)+4)/3))`

If A2 really must show 12/1/24, then put `$A$2-1` in both places instead of `$A$2`

Comment: Thanks, zsalya,

A query though, this formula is not switching to next quarter whenever there is change of year. for example, December 2024 is Quarter 1 then Jan - March 2025 should be Quarter 2, and so on.

Comment: With 11/30/24 in A2, and dates in D1 going to the right, copying this formula into D2 and dragging across does give me 2 under Jan, Feb and March 2025. Have you got the inputs and formula in exactly those cells? Have you got you input dates as dates, rather than strings - to check, change the format temporarily to number and you should see numbers between 45000 and 46000.